# How can I avoid seeing the rendering of Cufon font replacement tool while loading a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, cufon

I've published a website and every page has an  or  element with Cufon (cufon-yui.js) and sometimes while the page is loading , the visitor can see the text replacement tool doing it's job. It looks bad, some users are asking about it.

Why would that be happening if I'm using it (cufon) like anybody else and I don't' see this text rendering issue happening in most sites.

Also, there's an issue happening as well, with the Hyperlinks that are using Cufon.

Sometimes the cursor (a hand that appears for hyperlinks) disappear , it's bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use one of the [google web fonts](http://code.google.com/webfonts) or [typeface](http://typeface.neocracy.org)/

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to your css should solve the issue:

```
.cufon-loading { 
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just started looking at Cufon, so I'm not sure I'm qualified to give an opinion, but I've read the IE has (or had) rendering issues and that you needed to add `<script type="text/javascript">Cufon.now();</script>` to the end of your body (right before the `</body>`. If you are running any other heavy scripts on the page, you might want to put them as low on the page as possible and place the `Cufon.now()` right above those scripts (place Cufon higher in priority). If that doesn't work, try hiding your Cufon elements with JS as soon as the DOM has loaded (`visibility:hidden`) and then unhide them when the `onload` event fires (though I'm not sure that's much better than the text flickering).

Comment: I did all of that already, and it's still an issue. bTW this is an .NET application.

Answer (score -4):

Use something better?: http://reisio.com/examples/webfonts/

(if you worry about distribution legality, replace your fonts with any of the numerous free clones available all over the internet)

Comment: For anyone insterested, this kind of downvote-blast is common.  When a user supplies a link to *anything*, they can reasonably expect to be downvoted.  If they supply a link to their own site, they will most likely be downvoted and flagged as spam.  People around here *really* don't like spam.  So the fact that this question is being beaten about the reputation with a lead pipe doesn't surprise me in the least.  Also, URL answers are bad practice, in general.  The URL goes away and the answer becomes useless.

Comment: The URI is still there, and the only reason it's there is because I couldn't find any existing bare bones example to link to.  Reproducing it everywhere would be simply wasteful.  I'll consider switching to a domain that has nothing to do with me, though, that will *obviously* be a good use of time. :p